# How to get O(n) from T(n) = T(n/2) + n?

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I know that with master theorem i'll have teta(n), but i'm trying to resolve the recurrence in other way like this:

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + n
T(n) = T(n/4) + 2n
T(n) = T(n/8) + 3n
.
.
.
T(n) = T(n/2^k) + kn
k=logn -> T(1) + **nlogn**
```

what's the problem?

Comment: The line `T(n) = T(n/4) + 2n` is wrong; you added `n` but you should have added `n/2` because you were substituting `T(n/2) = T(n/4) + n/2`.

Comment: Think how the input paramter of T is bound in n if k is log-bound in n

Comment: This question would better fit the cs.stackexchange in my opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two steps involved in solving a recurrence relation from scratch:

1. Somehow find the answer
2. Prove that it's correct

The "Somehow find the answer part" can be hard. Usual ways are to expand a few terms and extrapolate, like Rodojf did in the other answer, graph/table it out and eyeball it, or recognize a familiar pattern.  All of those ways work pretty well for your example.

Let's put a few points in a table or graph (letting C = T(1)):

```
 n  |  T(n)
===========
 1  |   C
 2  |   C + 2
 4  |   C + 6
 8  |   C + 14
16  |   C + 30
```

Looks to me like T(n) = 2n - 2 + C

We can prove T(2<sup>x</sup>) = 2<sup>x+1</sup> - 2 + C to be correct for all x>=0 by induction:

- If *x=0*, then 2<sup>x+1</sup> - 2 + C = C, so T(2<sup>x</sup>) = 2<sup>x+1</sup> - 2 + C, from the table
- For any x, T(2<sup>x</sup>) = 2<sup>x+1</sup> - 2 + C ⇒ T(2<sup>x+1</sup>) = 2<sup>x+1</sup> - 2 + C + 2<sup>x+1</sup> = 2<sup>(x+1)+1</sup> - 2 + C, by substitution

So the fact that the formula is correct for n=2<sup>0</sup> implies that it is correct for all n=2<sup>x</sup>

To cover all the other values of n, you should also note that there is always some 2<sup>x</sup> between n and 2n, and between n/2 and n, and that their values of T(2<sup>x</sup>) bound T(n).

This is a fair bit of work for one single case... which is why we remember the master theorem, which has been proven for *all* of the cases that match its patterns.

Answer (score 0):

```
T(n)=T(n/2)+n=T(n/2^2)+n/2+n=T(n/2^3)+n/2^2+n/2+n= ... =  
=T(n/2^k)+n/2^(k-1)+n/2^(n-2)+...+n=  
=T(n/2^k)+n*(1-(1/2)^k)/(1-1/2)=  
=T(n/2^k)+2*n*(1-(1/2)^k)<=  
<=T(n/2^k)+2*n
```

If you know that T is a function defined and bounded in (0,0+e) for some small e>0 then you can conclude that T is O(n).

Answer (score -1):

In the last chapters of [Foundations of Algorithms - Richard E. Neapolitan.pdf](https://github.com/davidkmw0810/argorithm/blob/master/Foundations%20of%20Algorithms%20-%20Richard%20E.%20Neapolitan.pdf) you find several way to solve recurrence relation .
some way like :
1- recurrence tree
2- change variable and differential equations

and also you can see [link](http://iiitdm.ac.in/old/Faculty_Teaching/Sadagopan/pdf/DAA/new/recurrence-relations-V3.pdf)